# Div and table not working properly in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, html-table, fluid-layout

I am making a microsite via Dreamweaver using the fluid layout. In it, I had my header and banner inside a table under a div like so:

```
<div id="divHeader">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 30px;"></td>
            <td style="vertical-align: middle; font-size: 1.3rem; font-weight: bold;">
                <p><span>Move Toward </span> <span class="hdr">Zero Unplanned Downtime</span></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">
                    <img src="images/Mining_site_1192x181-12.png" alt=""/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

In most browsers, this works well (including mobile browsers):

[image: banner in Chrome]

Unfortunately, in Firefox, it's shown this way:

[image: banner in Firefox]

When I used the built-in Inspect Elemet, this is what I see in Firefox:

[image: Firefox Inspect Element]

For some reason, the table is displayed outside the DIV element. The table doesn't have a CSS class associated with it, and as for the DID, this is the CSS for its class divHeader:

```
#divHeader {
    font-family: Arial;
    background-color: #F89329;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 1rem;
    border: none;
}
```

Is there an issue with tables within div in Firefox? If so, what's a good workaround?

Here is my CSS code:

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* Simple fluid media
   Note: Fluid media requires that you remove the media's height and width attributes from the HTML
   http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fluid-images/ 
*/
img, object, embed, video {
    max-width: 100%;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a: hover {
    color: #F59D51;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* IE 6 does not support max-width so default to width 100% */
.ie6 img {
    width:100%;
}

/*
    Dreamweaver Fluid Grid Properties
    ----------------------------------
    dw-num-cols-mobile:     4;
    dw-num-cols-tablet:     8;
    dw-num-cols-desktop:    12;
    dw-gutter-percentage:   25;

    Inspiration from "Responsive Web Design" by Ethan Marcotte 
    http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design

    and Golden Grid System by Joni Korpi
    http://goldengridsystem.com/
*/

.fluid {
    clear: both;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    display: block;
}

.fluidList {
    list-style:none;
    list-style-image:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;        
}

/* Mobile Layout: 480px and below. */

.gridContainer {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 86.45%;
    padding-left: 0.75%;
    padding-right: 0.75%;
    margin: auto;
    clear: none;
    float: none;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.zeroMargin_mobile {
    margin-left: 0;
}

.hide_mobile {
    display: none;
}

#divEPMLogo {
    background-color:#fff;
}

#divHeader {
    font-family: Arial;
    background-color: #F89329;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 1rem;
    border: none;
}

#divHeader td.tdBanner {
    background-image: url(../images/Mining_site_v2_Banner480.png);
    background-position: bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    height: 181px;
    max-width: 480px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#divSubheader {
    font-family: Arial;
    background-color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: #4D4F44;
    line-height: 1.3rem;
    border: none;
}

div.divCnt {
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
}

#content header {
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #4D4F44;
    font-family: Arial;
}

#content article {
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: #818183;
    font-family: Arial;
}

#content hr {
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    color: #FFD022;
    background-color: #FFD022;
    border: none;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

div.divBack {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

div.divBack a {
    color: #818183;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.divBack a:hover {
    color: #F89329;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.divRMBtn {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #F89329;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    width: 6rem;
    padding: 3px 0px;
    font-family: Arial;
}

div.divRMBtn a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.divRMBtn a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.divSecFt {
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    font-style: italic;
    font-family: Arial;
    padding: 10px 0px;
}

div.divSecFt a {
    color: #4D4F44;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.divSecFt a:hover {
    color: #F89329;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.container1 {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid black;
    /*padding: 0px 0px 0px 30px;*/
    position: relative;
    left: 30px;
}

div.divForm {
    font-family:Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
    font-size: 1rem; 
    text-align: left; width:50%; 
    height: 26rem; 
    min-width: 320px; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    color:#4B4B4B; 
    border: none;
}

span.hdr {
    color: #4D4F44;
    text-wrap: none;
}

span.hdr2 {
    color: #F59D51;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}

td.td-ico {
    width: 73px;
    max-width: 73px;
    min-width: 73px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

.ulNltr{
    color: #4D4F44;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    line-height: 1rem;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

.ulNltr li {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    list-style-image:url(../images/icons/bullet.png)
}

.ulNltr li.q1 {
    list-style-image:url(../images/icons/question_icon.jpg)
}

.ulNltr li.c1 {
    list-style-image:url(../images/icons/contact_icon.jpg)
}

.ulNltr a {
    color: #4D4F44;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.ulNltr a:hover {
    color: #F89329;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Tablet Layout: 481px to 768px. Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout. */

@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {

.gridContainer {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 90.675%; /*width: 480px;*/
    padding-left: 0.75%;
    padding-right: 0.75%;
    margin: auto;
    clear: none;
    float: none;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.zeroMargin_tablet {
    margin-left: 0;
}

.hide_tablet {
    display: none;
}

#divEPMLogo {
    background-color:#fff;
}

#divHeader {
    font-family: Arial;
    background-color: #F89329;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 1rem;
    border: none;
}

#divHeader td.tdBanner {
    background-image: url(../images/Mining_site_v2_Banner768.png);
    background-position: bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    height: 181px;
    max-width: 480px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#divSubheader {
    font-family: Arial;
    background-color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: #4D4F44;
    line-height: 1.3rem;
    border: none;
}

div.divCnt {
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
}

#content header {
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #4D4F44;
    font-family: Arial;
}

#content article {
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: #818183;
    font-family: Arial;
}

#content hr {
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    color: #FFD022;
    background-color: #FFD022;
    border: none;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

div.divBack {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

div.divBack a {
    color: #818183;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.divBack a:hover {
    color: #F89329;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.divRMBtn {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #F89329;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    width: 6rem;
    padding: 3px 0px;
    font-family: Arial;
}

div.divRMBtn a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.divRMBtn a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.divSecFt {
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    font-style: italic;
    font-family: Arial;
    padding: 10px 0px;
}

div.divSecFt a {
    color: #4D4F44;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.divSecFt a:hover {
    color: #F89329;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.container1 {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid black;
    /*padding: 0px 0px 0px 30px;*/
    position: relative;
    left: 30px;
}

div.divForm {
    font-family:Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
    font-size: 1rem; 
    text-align: left; width:50%; 
    height: 26rem; 
    min-width: 320px; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    color:#4B4B4B; 
    border: none;
}

span.hdr {
    color: #4D4F44;
    text-wrap: none;
}

span.hdr2 {
    color: #F59D51;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}

td.td-ico {
    width: 73px;
    max-width: 73px;
    min-width: 73px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

.ulNltr{
    color: #4D4F44;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    line-height: 1rem;
}

.ulNltr li {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    list-style-image:url(../images/icons/bullet.png)
}

.ulNltr a {
    color: #4D4F44;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.ulNltr a:hover {
    color: #F89329;
    text-decoration: none;
}
}

/* Desktop Layout: 769px to a max of 1079px.  Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout and Tablet Layout. */

@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {

.gridContainer {
    width: 88.5%; /*width: 768px;*/
    max-width: 768px;
    padding-left: 0.75%;
    padding-right: 0.75%;
    margin: auto;
    clear: none;
    float: none;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.zeroMargin_desktop {
    margin-left: 0;
}

.hide_desktop {
    display: none;
}

#divEPMLogo {
    background-color:#fff;
}

#divHeader {
    font-family: Arial;
    background-color: #F89329;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 1rem;
    border: none;
}

#divHeader td.tdBanner {
    background-image: url(../images/Mining_site_v2_Banner768.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    height: 181px;
    max-width: 768px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#divSubheader {
    font-family: Arial;
    background-color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: #4D4F44;
    line-height: 1.3rem;
    border: none;
}

div.divCnt {
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
    border: none;
}

#content header {
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #4D4F44;
    font-family: Arial;
}

#content article {
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: #818183;
    font-family: Arial;
}

#content hr {
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    color: #FFD022;
    background-color: #FFD022;
    border: none;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

div.cntRw {
    display: table-cell;
}

div.divBack {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

div.divBack a {
    color: #818183;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.divBack a:hover {
    color: #F89329;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.divRMBtn {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #F89329;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    width: 6rem;
    padding: 3px 0px;
    font-family: Arial;
}

div.divRMBtn a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.divRMBtn a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.divSecFt {
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    font-style: italic;
    font-family: Arial;
    padding: 10px 0px;
}

div.divSecFt a {
    color: #4D4F44;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.divSecFt a:hover {
    color: #F89329;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.container1 {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid black;
    /*padding: 0px 0px 0px 30px;*/
    position: relative;
    left: 30px;
}

div.divForm {
    font-family:Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
    font-size: 1rem; 
    text-align: left; width:50%; 
    height: 26rem; 
    min-width: 320px; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    color:#4B4B4B; 
    border: none;
}

span.hdr {
    color: #4D4F44;
    text-wrap: none;
}

span.hdr2 {
    color: #F59D51;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}

td.td-ico {
    width: 73px;
    max-width: 73px;
    min-width: 73px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

.ulNltr{
    color: #4D4F44;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    line-height: 1rem;
}

.ulNltr li {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    list-style-image:url(../images/icons/bullet.png)
}

.ulNltr a {
    color: #4D4F44;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.ulNltr a:hover {
    color: #F89329;
    text-decoration: none;
}
}

/* Desktop Layout: 1080p and beyond.  Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout and Tablet Layout. */

@media only screen and (min-width: 1079px) {

.gridContainer {
    width: 88.5%; /*width: 1192px; */
    max-width: 1192px;
    padding-left: 0.75%;
    padding-right: 0.75%;
    margin: auto;
    clear: none;
    float: none;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.zeroMargin_desktop {
    margin-left: 0;
}

.hide_desktop {
    display: none;
}

#divEPMLogo {
    background-color:#fff;
}

#divHeader {
    font-family: Arial;
    background-color: #F89329;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 1rem;
    border: none;
    clear: right;
}

#divHeader td.tdBanner {
    background-image: url(../images/Mining_site_1192x181-12.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    height: 181px;
    max-width: 1191px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#divSubheader {
    font-family: Arial;
    background-color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: #4D4F44;
    line-height: 1.3rem;
    border: none;
}

div.divCnt {
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
    border: none;
}

#content header {
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #4D4F44;
    font-family: Arial;
}

#content article {
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: #818183;
    font-family: Arial;
}

#content hr {
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    color: #FFD022;
    background-color: #FFD022;
    border: none;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

div.cntRw {
    display: table-cell;
}

div.divBack {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px;
}

div.divBack a {
    color: #818183;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.divBack a:hover {
    color: #F89329;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.divRM {
    color: #818183;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    font-family: Arial;
}

div.divRMBtn {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #F89329;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    width: 6rem;
    padding: 3px 0px;
    font-family: Arial;
}

div.divRMBtn a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.divRMBtn a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.divSecFt {
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    font-style: italic;
    font-family: Arial;
    padding: 10px 0px;
}

div.divSecFt a {
    color: #4D4F44;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.divSecFt a:hover {
    color: #F89329;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.container1 {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid black;
    /*padding: 0px 0px 0px 30px;*/
    position: relative;
    left: 30px;
}

div.divForm {
    font-family:Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
    font-size: 1rem; 
    text-align: left; width:50%; 
    height: 26rem; 
    min-width: 320px; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    color:#4B4B4B; 
    border: none;
}

span.hdr {
    color: #4D4F44;
    text-wrap: none;
}

span.hdr2 {
    color: #F59D51;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}

td.td-ico {
    width: 73px;
    max-width: 73px;
    min-width: 73px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

.ulNltr{
    color: #4D4F44;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    line-height: 1rem;
}

.ulNltr li {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    list-style-image:url(../images/icons/bullet.png)
}

.ulNltr a {
    color: #4D4F44;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.ulNltr a:hover {
    color: #F89329;
    text-decoration: none;
}
}
```

Comment: try to valid you html first http://validator.w3.org/ see if there is any extra/unclosed  tags...

Comment: try adding this:
clear:right;

Comment: @sdcr          I tried the validator, there were no unclosed taqs :(

Comment: @JeanGkol      I added the code in the layout for 1080p and beyond (see code above), but it didn't do a thing :(  BTW, this is the first time that I'm coding for a fluid layout, so any tips would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: For some reason, adding a border alleviated the problem in Firefox. However, I noticed that the whole banner doesn't automatically adjust in width the same way it does in other browsers :(

Comment: see my answer, I really tested and it worked fine. I don't know if you see no works since I use my own site test page to try it out

Answer (score 0):

It does seem that Firefox is having problems with the table within the div. I changed the HTML part to this:

```html
 <!-- Page header and banner -->
   <div id="divHeader">
    <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
     <p>Move Toward <span class="hdr">Zero Unplanned Downtime</span></p>
     </div>
   </div>
  
   <div id="divHBanner">
    <img src="images/Mining_site_1192x181-12.png" alt=""/>
   </div>
    <!-- End Page header and banner -->
```

It fixed the original error, but it opened up another. I will post a separate question for that instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried in jsfiddle and in my web test page and everything is okay when I remove `@charset"utf-8";`

when I set it again, it went collided again